# WordPress pages outside install directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have WordPress installed in a subdirectory and I'd like one WordPress page to appear as if it's on the root.

Eg.
/wordpress/mypage

To appear as:
/mypage

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Apache, and you've got permalinks already working, you can use an `.htaccess` file in your document root to rewrite `yoursite.com/wordpress/mypage` to `yoursite.com/mypage`.

If you don't already have a `.htaccess` file in your document root, create one and put this in:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteRule ^mypage$ wordpress/mypage`

I'm no `.htaccess` expert, but that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Erik,
But sadly I've already tried this and to no luck, there is another .htaccess file in the root that I think is interfering with it. I'll keep at it and let you know how it goes.

Comment: What is in the existing `.htaccess`?